# VBA random function

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA beginner. and I am confused about how to add one line of code here
to represent x as a random number between “low” and “high”.

```
  Dim low As Integer, high As Integer
  Dim x As Double
  low = InputBox("Lower Bound:", " Please input a number as", -18)
  high = InputBox("Upper Bound:", "Please input a number as", 18)
  x = ("low:","high:".Rnd()) at here
```

I don't know how fix this code

Comment: See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement

Comment: assign `high` and `low`, then you can use `(high-low)*rnd()+low` to bet a number between them

Comment: @SpectralInstance - That reference doesn't seem to be directly related to the issue here.

Comment: This isn't valid code: `x = ("low:","high:".Rnd()) at here`. Where did you get this from?

Comment: @Enigmativity Re SpectralInstances link: see the contained Example "Generate random value between 1 and 6." Re your comment "This isn't valid code" - it's clearly pseudo code, trying to explain what the OP wants.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In case you want to generate an **integer** between `low` and `high` in VBA you may use [RandBetween](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.randbetween)